# how to validate an HTML5 form and not post the form?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with some html attributes like:

```
<form>
      <label>Full  Name</label>

      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="span3" required="required">
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="span3" required="required">
      <label>Username</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="span3" required="required">
      <label>Password</label>
```

when user clicks on button, I want the html5 to apply validattion rules.

If the validations rules are OK, then do not submit the form, but use some $_POST ajax

Any idea ?

Comment: should not be done using javascript or jquery ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`checkValidity()` will validate the form using the native HTML5 validation :

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) { // or on button click ?
    e.preventDefault()

    var valid = e.target.checkValidity();

    if (valid) {
        // do ajax
    }
});
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms_in_HTML):

> On HTMLFormElement objects, the checkValidity() method, which returns
>   true if all of this form element's associated elements that are
>   subject to constraint validation satisfy their constraints, and false
>   if any do not.

Note that it might not be supported in all browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
 if (e.target.checkValidity() === false)
 {
   e.preventDefault(); // disable the "normal" action of submit
 }
});
```